# GET variable not being sent through AJAX call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I'm trying to send a variable using AJAX GET method but no matter what I do it doesn't get sent. The PHP file always returns 3, which means that the variable q was never received in the PHP file.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myonclickhandler(t) {
        var session = " <?php echo ($_SESSION['Username']); ?> ";
        if(!(session==null))
        {
            var val = t.value;
            if (t.checked) {

                var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                        var show = xmlhttp.responseText;

                        if(show==3)
                        {
                            alert(show);
                        }
                    }
                };

                xmlhttp.open("GET", "<?php echo site_url('Buyer_controller/ajax_cart_load?q='); ?>"+ 129, true);
                xmlhttp.send();

            }

        }
    }
</script>
```

**Buyer_controller/ajax_cart_load**

```
public function ajax_cart_load()
    {
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->model("Cart_model", "cartm");

        if(isset($_REQUEST["q"]))
        {
            $check = $_REQUEST["q"];

            $result = $this->cartm->populate_cart($check);
            $val = $result->value;
            $name= $result->Brand." Gift Card";
            $quantity= $result->Quantity;

            $data2 = array(
                'id' => $check,
                'qty' => 1,
                'price' => $val,
                'name' => $name,
                'options' => array('Quantity' => $quantity, 'PDID' => $check )
            );

            if($this->cart->insert($data2))
            {
                echo 1;
            }
            else
            {
                echo 0;
            }


        }
        else
        {
            echo 3;
        }

    }
```

Comment: In the network tab of developer console of the browser you can see the request. What's the url of this request?

Comment: Try putting it as xmlhttp.send(null);

Comment: Sergey, the URL in developer console of the browser is `http://localhost/emailgifts/index.php?/Buyer_controller/ajax_cart_load?q=129`

Comment: Pixel, I tried `xmlhttp.send(null);`. No improvement unfortunately.

Comment: try this with $_POST method

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that in `$_REQUEST` the name of the variable was not "q" but "/Buyer_controller/ajax_cart_load?q". And the name of the variable in `$_GET` was "q". So I just used `$_GET` in the PHP file instead of `$_REQUEST` and it worked like a charm. :)